# Retrieve ERRORLEVEL From Executed Script

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, wsh

I'm executing my VBScript as below:

```
cscript autoFix.vbs /ignoreBO /sCompServiceList:EPMA,FR
```

It fails with below error:

> D:\autofix\autoFix.vbs(988, 2) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'LogFile'

This is ok.

But

```
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

outputs zero when I need all run-time errors to be caught with non-zero.

Can anyone tell me how to set the `ERRORLEVEL` for errors returned by VBScript?

Comment: Well first off it would be helpful to see `autoFix.vbs` added to the question via [edit], especially line 988 which seems to be the cause of the error.

Comment: The error is completely irrelevant; the problem is the setting of ERRORLEVEL.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner your right, good catch...I was looking at the error and thinking what do they expect us to do with that. So this is really a batch question and has nothing to do with VBScript.

Comment: Similar - http://stackoverflow.com/q/23648890/692942

Comment: This is the second time this week that a perfectly good question is closed.

Comment: @Lankymart, I don't think so. Windows scripting host set the exit code to 1 for compilation errors, but will not set the exit code for runtime errors. It is not a problem on how to detect the error from the batch side, but how to propagate the error so it can be detected.

Comment: @MCND I know, see [latest comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853032/retrieve-errorlevel-from-executed-script#comment70891380_41853032).

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner it's been closed, but for the wrong reason...it's pretty much identical issue to the duplicate I've posted. Either way, it's not a *"perfectly good question"*.

Comment: @Lankymart, You are right, it is a duplicate. I started to comment before you post the link. Thank you

Comment: See [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.scripting.wsh/29y_8op0Yww): _"I urge Microsoft to fix CSCRIPT.EXE, so that ERRORLEVEL of zero will only be returned when WScript.quit(n) is called with n=0, or when the script comes to a normal conclusion with no errors"_.